# not able to set selected value for Html.Dropdown list

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to set a selected value (value returned from JSon result) for my Html.Dropdownlist. The dropdown list already has this value.
For instance :Json returned value:abc ,this value is already there in the DDL

Jquery

```
   $("#ACTION").each(function (state) {
     if (this.Value == state.value)
    {      
      var theText=state.value;
      $('#ACTION').val(theText); //I think its not suppose to be like this
    });
```

the if condition satisfies but when i try to set the value nothing happens

DDL

```
  @Html.DropDownList("ACTION", ViewBag.ACTDICT_ACTION as SelectList)
```

what I am trying to do is that the ddl (id:ACTION)displays the value that Json has be retuned along with other values .

Any help will be appreciated .
Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

In DDL in your view bag, this is your list right? I am assuming its an array of things like this:

```
new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="False"}
```

for the one you want selected, initialize it like this before passing it through the ViewBag

```
new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="False", Selected="True"}
```

Comment: I tied your suggestion but I think my Jquery is wrong.  I am not sure how to first check and then display an existing value in the DDL